# Warnings and errors in R function ("In regularize.values(x, y, ties, missing(ties)) : collapsing to unique 'x' values")

Tags: r, function, warnings

I have warnings and errors in a function on a computer that do not appear when I'm running the function on another computer. 
The warnings `"In regularize.values(x, y, ties, missing(ties)) : collapsing to unique 'x' values"` suddenly appeared few weeks ago and I cannot run my complete simulations without getting errors.

I don't know what to do. I've compared the two session information (below) without finding anything.
I thought this may be a problem with the R version, I updated the R version on the second computer (the one with the warnings) without causing the suppresion of warnings.

Is there anyhthing I can check to solve this problem?

Thanks in advance for any help!

After the comments, I've posted a new question [here][1]

**1. Computer with warnings**

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.6.3 (2020-02-29)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: CentOS Linux 7 (Core)

Matrix products: default
BLAS:   /usr/local/R-3.6.3/lib64/R/lib/libRblas.so
LAPACK: /usr/local/R-3.6.3/lib64/R/lib/libRlapack.so

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=fr_FR.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C              
 [3] LC_TIME=fr_FR.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=fr_FR.UTF-8    
 [5] LC_MONETARY=fr_FR.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=fr_FR.UTF-8   
 [7] LC_PAPER=fr_FR.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                 
 [9] LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C            
[11] LC_MEASUREMENT=fr_FR.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] boot_1.3-24       lme4_1.1-21       Matrix_1.2-18     frailtySurv_1.3.6
[5] coxme_2.2-16      bdsmatrix_1.3-4   survival_3.1-11   statmod_1.4.34   

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_1.0.4          nloptr_1.2.2.1      pillar_1.4.3       
 [4] compiler_3.6.3      plyr_1.8.6          tools_3.6.3        
 [7] lifecycle_0.2.0     tibble_2.1.3        nlme_3.1-145       
[10] gtable_0.3.0        lattice_0.20-40     pkgconfig_2.0.3    
[13] rlang_0.4.5         rstudioapi_0.11     Bolstad2_1.0-28    
[16] dplyr_0.8.5         stringr_1.4.0       grid_3.6.3         
[19] tidyselect_1.0.0    glue_1.3.2          R6_2.4.1           
[22] minqa_1.2.4         ggplot2_3.3.0       purrr_0.3.3        
[25] reshape2_1.4.3      magrittr_1.5        scales_1.1.0       
[28] splines_3.6.3       MASS_7.3-51.5       assertthat_0.2.1   
[31] colorspace_1.4-1    nleqslv_3.3.2       numDeriv_2016.8-1.1
[34] stringi_1.4.6       munsell_0.5.0       crayon_1.3.4
```

**2. Computer without warnings**

````
R version 3.5.1 (2018-07-02)
Platform: i386-w64-mingw32/i386 (32-bit)
Running under: Windows 7 x64 (build 7601) Service Pack 1

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=French_France.1252  LC_CTYPE=French_France.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=French_France.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                  
[5] LC_TIME=French_France.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods  
[7] base     

other attached packages:
[1] boot_1.3-24       lme4_1.1-21       Matrix_1.2-18    
[4] frailtySurv_1.3.6 coxme_2.2-16      bdsmatrix_1.3-4  
[7] survival_3.1-11   statmod_1.4.34   

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] minqa_1.2.4         R6_2.4.1            splines_3.5.1      
 [4] Bolstad2_1.0-28     scales_1.1.0        assertthat_0.2.1   
 [7] grid_3.5.1          stringr_1.4.0       nleqslv_3.3.2      
[10] numDeriv_2016.8-1.1 tidyselect_1.0.0    munsell_0.5.0      
[13] pillar_1.4.3        compiler_3.5.1      tibble_2.1.3       
[16] lattice_0.20-35     pkgconfig_2.0.3     purrr_0.3.3        
[19] rstudioapi_0.11     ggplot2_3.3.0       MASS_7.3-50        
[22] plyr_1.8.6          glue_1.3.2          stringi_1.4.6      
[25] magrittr_1.5        reshape2_1.4.3      gtable_0.3.0       
[28] rlang_0.4.5         colorspace_1.4-1    yaml_2.2.1         
[31] tools_3.5.1         lifecycle_0.2.0     dplyr_0.8.5        
[34] nloptr_1.2.2.1      nlme_3.1-137        crayon_1.3.4       
[37] Rcpp_1.0.4  ```






  [1]: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60934150/is-it-possible-to-use-an-old-version-of-stats-package-in-r
````

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I saw this answer however I have no clue where the 'regularize.values'  function is called in my code! I would not know where to act.

Comment: Run your model in debug?

Comment: Neither would we Flora - you haven't included your code! We know what the problem is, but can't fix it if you don't show us the piece of code you have that throws an error

Comment: You're perfectly right :-) However my code is very very long and calls several other functions (several of them, from R packages). Anyway your comment gave me a lead! One of the link in the answer you've quoted indicates "The internal regularize.values() auxiliary of approx(), splinefun() etc now warns again when there are ties and the caller did not specify ties. Further, it no longer duplicates x and y unnecessarily when x is already sorted" in the R3.6.0 version. I must search how to suppress this warning without knowing where this function is called.

Comment: I've posted a new question :-)

Comment: Link it here :-)