# Is it possible to use an old version of 'stats' package in R?

Tags: r, error-handling, warnings

**Is it possible to use an old version of the `stats` package in R?**

The function `stats:::regularize.values` causes me warnings and errors in the last R version (any version >3.5).
I have no possibility to get back to an old R version.
I have no clue where the `regularize.values` function is called in my code since I use several functions, some of them from different R packages.
I've tried to change the call to `regularize.values` in my code by doing

```
assignInNamespace("regularize.values", regularize.values.old.version, ns = "stats")
```

But I got the error:

```
Error in assignInNamespace("regularize.values", regularize.values.OV,  : 
  locked binding of ‘regularize.values’ cannot be changed
```

Thanks in advance for your suggestions!

Comment: i can't reproduce your error, but `?bindenv` might be useful. are you getting errors and not just "collapsing to unique 'x' values" warnings? if there are not errors, I would just ignore those warnings

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I have the error `In regularize.values(x, y, ties, missing(ties)) :
  collapsing to unique 'x' values` when I'm running juste one function. But when I'm using parallelization and runing several functions, I got error in many cases, in a similar way than the user here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56861001/how-to-suppress-warnings-from-statsregularize-values

Comment: A warning is not the same as an error. Please use proper terminology. If you get an error you should provide an example. Warnings can be suppressed if you are sure you want to ignore them. I would advise against changing a function in stat's namespace.

Comment: I got the error `"Error in fitfrai (..]  Frailty distribution initial parameters out of range. Parameters for lognormal frailty must be in: (0.01, Inf)\n". I think I will follow your advice. The error may be caused by something else...

Comment: @Roland I ran the parallelized code on an older R version and I still got the error!  I need to make some additional investigations. But you are right, the bug are not caused by the warnings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this:

```r
assignInNamespace("regularize.values", regularize.values.OV, 
                  ns="stats", envir = as.environment("package:stats"))
```

However, it will only work if the error is not thrown by a package that depends on the already-loaded `stats`

---

Therefore, a working solution should be:

```r
assignInNamespace("regularize.values", function(x, y, ties) {
    x <- xy.coords(x, y)
    y <- x$y
    x <- x$x
    if(any(na <- is.na(x) | is.na(y))) {
    ok <- !na
    x <- x[ok]
    y <- y[ok]
    }
    nx <- length(x)
    if (!identical(ties, "ordered")) {
        o <- order(x)
    x <- x[o]
    y <- y[o]
    if (length(ux <- unique(x)) < nx) {
        # if (missing(ties))
        # warning("collapsing to unique 'x' values")
        y <- as.vector(tapply(y,match(x,x),ties))
        x <- ux
        stopifnot(length(y) == length(x))
    }
    }
    list(x=x, y=y)
}, ns="stats", envir = as.environment("package:stats"))
```

Comment: Thanks  a lot for your answer. This does not solve the error caused by the binding of the `stats` environment. In the meantime, I found that the error may no be caused by the initial warnings. I will continues my searches on my side. Thanks a lot for all your suggestions anyway